# How to link jquery file with html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML file that is supposed to link to a file that only contains some jquery functions but I'm not being able to do so. This is where the images of both the HTML and the jquery are the ones below. I tried to do some stuff but I guess they were all wrong. I want to link that HTML file to the jquery file. How can I it? What's lacking in my code?

This is the jquery or jqueryUI don't know what is what:

```
$(function() {

$('#docwindow').droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    cursor: 'move',
    greedy: true,
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass('out-of-box')) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
            console.log("Removing element");
        } else {
            $(ui.draggable).removeClass("out-of-box").addClass("in-box");
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
            console.log("Cloning element");
        }

    }
});

$('body').droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    cursor: 'move',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("Dropping");
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass("in-box")) {
            var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
            clone.removeClass("in-box").addClass("out-of-box");
            clone.detach().appendTo($(this)).draggable({});
            ui.draggable.draggable({
                revert: true
            });
        }
    }
});

$("#docwindow, .draggable").draggable({});
$("#body").draggable({});
});
```

This is the header of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PF1.1.novo.css">
    <script src="PF1.1.jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code *in the question*, not in images.  If you read **[ask]** it will explain how to ask a good question.

Comment: Add as the very first line (on its own) of the .js file: `alert("included")` - if you get that then it's something else.  If you don't get it, then check your browser network tab

Comment: Most likely, you've not included jquery (it's not in your off-site images)

Comment: Also note that the `draggable()` and `droppable()` are part of jQueryUI (not jQuery) so you will need to include both libraries. See http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). I would also suggest that you [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

To use jquery functions, you must include the jquery library.
This website makes very good tutorials, i recommend this page to you, it should solve your problem :
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. In this case the jQuery learning centre is a much more applicable source: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll double check next time I see something on this website.

Comment: I included this `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>` in my code as it says in the w3schools tutorial but it still doesn't work

Comment: You should give the debugger output so we can help you finding the problem. If you are using chrome you just have to right click on your page then inspect element. Access the console tab in the new opened area. Here you should see some output.

Comment: "still doesn't work" is too vague - does the file fail to load? does it load but does nothing? does it load but give console errors? does your monitor explode?